# damped oscillation graph in LaTex

Tags: graphics

can anyone help me to draw this graph in LaTex? documentclass{beamer} [image]

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please consider posting a code in which you show what you tried when posting your next question.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain=0:5,samples=501,axis lines=center,
    xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,
    xlabel={$t$},xlabel style={anchor=west},
    ylabel={$v(t)$},ylabel style={anchor=south}]
    \addplot[color=blue,no marks,very thick,smooth] {(1-exp(-x)*cos(10*deg(x)))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you can do that in (pretty much) any document class. `standalone` is just very convenient for these kinds of things because it crops at the bounding box. As a rule of thumb, you can combine most document classes with most packages, yet there are some incompatibilities and sometimes the order in which packages are to be loaded matters, but to first approximation it does not.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Damped (or damned? ;-) oscillations}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain=0:5,samples=501,axis lines=center,
    xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,
    xlabel={$t$},xlabel style={anchor=west},
    ylabel={$v(t)$},ylabel style={anchor=south}]
    \addplot[color=blue,no marks,very thick,smooth] {(1-exp(-x)*cos(10*deg(x)))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: can you do it on documentclass{ beamer} ?

Comment: @ANdy Yes you can.